# django templatetags path on deployment server not found

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I created a django app with a custom templatetags.
In my directory I have a folder

> /templatetags/

and they are loaded from there
but I get the following error on deployment server:

```
'solo_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library solo_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.solo_tags,localeurl.templatetags.solo_tags,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.solo_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.solo_tags
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://siaab.alwaysdata.net/en/about/mission/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
'solo_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library solo_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.solo_tags,localeurl.templatetags.solo_tags,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.solo_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.solo_tags
Exception Location: /usr/local/alwaysdata/python/django/1.4.3/django/template/defaulttags.py in load, line 1043
Python Executable:  /usr/languages/python/2.6/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.6
Python Path:    
['/home/modules/',
 '/home/siaab',
 '/home/siaab/abengineering',
 '/home/siaab/abengineering/public',
 '/home/siaab/modules/django_localeurl-1.5-py2.6.egg',
 '/home/siaab/modules/django_solo-1.0.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.4-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Paste-1.6-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/trac-0.10.5-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lamson-1.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_daemon-1.5.5-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mock-0.7.0b2-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lockfile-0.8-py2.6.egg',
 '/home/siaab/modules',
 '/usr/local/alwaysdata/python/django/1.4.3',
 '/usr/languages/python/2.6/lib/python26.zip',
 '/usr/languages/python/2.6/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/languages/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/languages/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/languages/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/languages/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/languages/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 1 Sep 2013 01:18:38 +0300
```

Please help!

Comment: Is the directory `templatetags` a sub-directory under your application directory? Does it have an `__init__.py` file in it?

Comment: I added this directory in the application directory and... It WORKS! Thank you! P.S. it looks like it's a small difference between app tree on localhost and server....

Comment: I added an answer then. :)

Comment: I've marked it as correct answer... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the directory `templatetags` a sub-directory under your application directory? Does it have an `__init__.py`? Is your application in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 1):

Put 'solo' into INSTALLED_APPS variable in settings.py file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. the solution described in the above comment works.